# I cannot log in to my ftp server

Tags: ftp, login

I am trying to connect to my ftp server on a Centos 6 machine from my local Windows machine, but everytime I try, I get a '530 Login incorrect' error.

This issue happens whether I use FileZilla or whether I connect using ftp from the command line.

```
# This is the ProFTPD configuration file
# $Id: proftpd.conf,v 1.1 2004/02/26 17:54:30 thias Exp $

ServerName          "ProFTPD server"
ServerIdent         on "FTP Server ready."
ServerAdmin         root@localhost
ServerType          standalone
#ServerType         inetd
DefaultServer           on
AccessGrantMsg          "User %u logged in."
#DisplayConnect         /etc/ftpissue
#DisplayLogin           /etc/ftpmotd
#DisplayGoAway          /etc/ftpgoaway
DeferWelcome            off

# Use this to excude users from the chroot
DefaultRoot         ~ !adm

# Use pam to authenticate (default) and be authoritative
AuthPAMConfig           proftpd
AuthOrder           mod_auth_pam.c* mod_auth_unix.c

# Do not perform ident nor DNS lookups (hangs when the port is filtered)
IdentLookups            off
UseReverseDNS           off

# Port 21 is the standard FTP port.
Port                21

# Umask 022 is a good standard umask to prevent new dirs and files
# from being group and world writable.
Umask               022

# Default to show dot files in directory listings
ListOptions         "-a"

# See Configuration.html for these (here are the default values)
#MultilineRFC2228       off
#RootLogin          off
#LoginPasswordPrompt        on
#MaxLoginAttempts       3
#MaxClientsPerHost      none
#AllowForeignAddress        off # For FXP

# Allow to resume not only the downloads but the uploads too
AllowRetrieveRestart        on
AllowStoreRestart       on

# To prevent DoS attacks, set the maximum number of child processes
# to 30.  If you need to allow more than 30 concurrent connections
# at once, simply increase this value.  Note that this ONLY works
# in standalone mode, in inetd mode you should use an inetd server
# that allows you to limit maximum number of processes per service
# (such as xinetd)
MaxInstances            20

# Set the user and group that the server normally runs at.
User                nobody
Group               nobody

# Disable sendfile by default since it breaks displaying the download speeds in
# ftptop and ftpwho
UseSendfile         no

# This is where we want to put the pid file
ScoreboardFile          /var/run/proftpd.score

# Normally, we want users to do a few things.
<Global>
  AllowOverwrite        yes
  <Limit ALL SITE_CHMOD>
    AllowAll
  </Limit>
</Global>

# Define the log formats
LogFormat           default "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %s %b"
LogFormat           auth    "%v [%P] %h %t \"%r\" %s"

# TLS
# Explained at http://www.castaglia.org/proftpd/modules/mod_tls.html
#TLSEngine          on
#TLSRequired            on
#TLSRSACertificateFile      /etc/pki/tls/certs/proftpd.pem
#TLSRSACertificateKeyFile   /etc/pki/tls/certs/proftpd.pem
#TLSCipherSuite         ALL:!ADH:!DES
#TLSOptions         NoCertRequest
#TLSVerifyClient        off
##TLSRenegotiate        ctrl 3600 data 512000 required off timeout 300
#TLSLog             /var/log/proftpd/tls.log

# SQL authentication Dynamic Shared Object (DSO) loading
# See README.DSO and howto/DSO.html for more details.
#<IfModule mod_dso.c>
#   LoadModule mod_sql.c
#   LoadModule mod_sql_mysql.c
#   LoadModule mod_sql_postgres.c
#</IfModule>

# A basic anonymous configuration, with an upload directory.
#<Anonymous ~ftp>
#  User             ftp
#  Group                ftp
#  AccessGrantMsg       "Anonymous login ok, restrictions apply."
#
#  # We want clients to be able to login with "anonymous" as well as "ftp"
#  UserAlias            anonymous ftp
#
#  # Limit the maximum number of anonymous logins
#  MaxClients           10 "Sorry, max %m users -- try again later"
#
#  # Put the user into /pub right after login
#  #DefaultChdir            /pub
#
#  # We want 'welcome.msg' displayed at login, '.message' displayed in
#  # each newly chdired directory and tell users to read README* files. 
#  DisplayLogin         /welcome.msg
#  DisplayFirstChdir        .message
#  DisplayReadme            README*
#
#  # Some more cosmetic and not vital stuff
#  DirFakeUser          on ftp
#  DirFakeGroup         on ftp
#
#  # Limit WRITE everywhere in the anonymous chroot
#  <Limit WRITE SITE_CHMOD>
#    DenyAll
#  </Limit>
#
#  # An upload directory that allows storing files but not retrieving
#  # or creating directories.
#  <Directory uploads/*>
#    AllowOverwrite     no
#    <Limit READ>
#      DenyAll
#    </Limit>
#
#    <Limit STOR>
#      AllowAll
#    </Limit>
#  </Directory>
#
#  # Don't write anonymous accesses to the system wtmp file (good idea!)
#  WtmpLog          off
#
#  # Logging for the anonymous transfers
#  ExtendedLog      /var/log/proftpd/access.log WRITE,READ default
#  ExtendedLog      /var/log/proftpd/auth.log AUTH auth
#
#</Anonymous>
```

It's not obvious to me from the configuration where the log file is; there's an `/etc/log/proftpd/` folder, but there are no files in it.

I can take the credentials I am trying to use to connect and successfully use those credentials to log in to the Centos machine.

What could I be doing wrong? Are ftp credentials different from the user credentials?

**EDIT**

I followed Zypher's instructions and looked in `var/log/secure`, and I saw this in several places:

```
Jan 16 08:08:17 vps-1150113-19757 proftpd: PAM unable to dlopen(/lib64/security/pam_stack.so): /lib64/security/pam_stack.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Jan 16 08:08:17 vps-1150113-19757 proftpd: PAM adding faulty module: /lib64/security/pam_stack.so
Jan 16 08:08:17 vps-1150113-19757 proftpd[22064]: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX[XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX]) - USER xxxxxxx (Login failed): Incorrect password.
```

It's interesting that the 'unable to dlopen' and 'adding faulty module' messages always appeared before the 'Incorrect password' entry. Is this significant?

I will do some research to see what this might mean.

Comment: What ftp server? How is it configured?

Comment: I'm using proftpd. Which configuration setting would you want me to provide?

Comment: All of proftpd.conf. What is in the proftpd logs when login fails? Have you read http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/Authentication.html and other relevant documenttion?

Comment: I've added the configuration. I read the documentation you pointed me to, but I couldn't find anything that could tell me what specifically what the issue was.

Comment: since you are using PAM for authentication check `/var/log/secure` for authentication fails.

Comment: Thanks, Zypher. I have updated the question with my findings.

Comment: OK, so I followed the instructions here: http://www.raymondpopowich.com/sys-admin/plesk-proftpd-pam_stack-so-file-directory/ This seems to have resolved my problems. Sciurus, Zypher, does any of you want to post a summary so I can mark it as the answer?